# How to match any character except \n in a multiline string in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex

```
def test_period_is_a_shortcut_for_any_non_newline_character
  assert_equal "abc123", "abc\n123"[/.*/m]
end
```

This test does not pass, as the expression `[/.*/m]` returns "abc\n123" instead of "abc123". What am I doing wrong? I am using `.` for non-newline characters, `*` to match all and `m` for multiline and yet it returns `\n` as well.

Comment: remove the `m`? That's the dotall flag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to match the newline, then remove the `/m` from the test

From http://www.regular-expressions.info/ruby.html :

> `/m` makes the dot match newlines. Ruby indeed uses `/m`, whereas Perl and many other programming languages use `/s` for "dot matches newlines".

Or indeed from the [official documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Regexp.html#label-Character+Classes):

> `/./` - Any character except a newline.
>
> `/./m` - Any character (the m modifier enables multiline mode)

As it stands, your test is an impossible one, you're trying to test that Ruby does the opposite of what it's designed to do (which, luckily, it doesn't).

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps it would be a solution to go solve the problem from the opposite direction, and removing the particular string you don't want.

```
"abc\n123".gsub(/\n/, '')
```